# How do I overset and underset with prescript, superscript, and subscripts?

Tags: alignment, subscripts, superscripts

I am trying to make over/underset play nicely with scripts. However, the alignment is wrong, and I am not sure how to fix it.

If I put the prescript in the overset and underset, i.e. `\underset{\beta}{\overset{\alpha}{\prescript{1}{4+5}{\Pi}}}`, I get this:

[image]

If I put the overset and underset inside the prescript, i.e. `\prescript{1}{4+5}{\underset{\beta}{\overset{\alpha}{\Pi}}}`, I get this:

[image]

However, this is what I want:

[image]

How is this achievable in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you want `\Pi`, or do you maybe want `\prod`? (`\Pi` is to `\prod` as `\Sigma` is to `\sum`.) Please advise.

Comment: I want `\Pi`, I picked it because I was trying to replicate Typst code in LaTeX for a project I was doing, and just copied from the Typst documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the prescripts to a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\adornPi}[4]{%
  \prescript{#1}{#2}{\vphantom{\Pi}}%
  \overset{#3}{\underset{#4}{\Pi}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\adornPi{1}{4+5}{\alpha}{\beta}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `sideset` from the `amsmath` package. It requires the use of a large operator, so `\prod` instead of `\Pi`. Left-side scripts are left-justified, so adding `\mathllap` (`mathtools`, which includes `amsmath`) will place the longer script where it belongs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\sideset{^1_{\mathllap{4+}5}}{}\prod^{\alpha}_{\beta}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if there's something in front of the symbol?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer combines some of the ideas in [@SandyG's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711785/5001) and [@egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711797/5001) answers. I use `\prod` rather than `\Pi`, while I also use `\prescript` rather than `\sideset`. The user macro `\adornprod` can be used in both text-style and display-style math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \prescript macro
\newcommand\adornprod[4]{%
   \prescript{#1}{#2}{\vphantom{\prod}}\prod\limits^{#3}_{#4}}
\begin{document}
$-\Pi\prod{\displaystyle\prod}{-} % illustrate size differences
 \qquad 
 \adornprod{1}{4+5}{\alpha}{\beta} 
 \qquad 
 \displaystyle 
 \adornprod{1}{4+5}{\alpha}{\beta}$
\end{document}
```